# Ambiguity in Pre & Post increment - C Programming

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

Writing a simple C program to understnad pre and post increment. I could understant case 1 and 3 but **not getting how the value of i becoming 15 and 16 in case 2 and 4 resp. Kindly share your thoughts about case 2 and 4.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i , j=6 ;
i=j++ + j++ ;
printf("Case 1 : With j=6 and i=j++ + j++ : i %d j %d\n",i,j);

j=6;
i=++j + j++ ;
printf("Case 2 : With j=6 and i=++j + j++ : i %d j %d\n",i,j);

j=6;
i=j++ + ++j ;
printf("Case 3 : With j=6 and i=j++ + ++j : i %d j %d\n",i,j);

j=6;
i=++j + ++j ;
printf("Case 4 : With j=6 and i=++j + ++j : i %d j %d\n",i,j);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I'm getting for the above code.

**OUTPUT :**

```
Case 1 : With j=6 and i=j++ + j++ : i 13 j 8
Case 2 : With j=6 and i=++j + j++ : i 15 j 8
Case 3 : With j=6 and i=j++ + ++j : i 14 j 8
Case 4 : With j=6 and i=++j + ++j : i 16 j 8
```

Thanks in advance.

I could understant case 1 and 3 but **not getting how the value of i becoming 15 and 16 in case 2 and 4 resp. Kindly share your thoughts about case 2 and 4.**

Comment: You need to, at least, understand the concepts of "order of evaluation", "sequence points", and "side effects". The "order of evaluation" within a single statement is unspecified. There usually is no "sequence point" within a statement. The (eventual) "side effects" of an expression can happen at any moment between enclosing sequence points.

Comment: There's a near identical question identified as a duplicate. Despite being a classic question when learning C it's not as easy to find the explanation as you think, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior